# 'make distcheck' target and the info/dir file

Tags: autotools, automake

I've added a new Info manual to my project, and added the requisite `Makefile.am` incantations:

```
info_TEXINFOS = manual.texi
```

Now when I run `make distcheck`, I get an error when verifying that `make uninstall` successfully uninstalls all files, because the `$(infodir)/dir` file isn't being removed correctly.

```
ERROR: files left after uninstall:
./share/info/dir
make[1]: *** [distuninstallcheck] Error 1
```

I searched the Internet, the Automake and Texinfo manuals for a solution, but came up blank. What is the idiomatic way to correct this and get `make distcheck` working again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`distuninstallcheck` does not (or should not) fail when there is only ONE file left after `uninstall`, precisely because of the `dir` file.  It should fail only when there are more than one file left.

Did you edit the output?  If you didn't, it's an Automake bug you should report.  If you did, you need not worry about this `dir` file, and just fix the problem with the other files that are listed.

The fact that Automake unconditionally ignores one file can hide a bug when you are not using TEXINFO manuals.  This bug would then surface when you add a manual.  It's unfortunate.

Comment: Good catch -- I did edit the output.  Our `make install` and `make uninstall` run `gtk-update-icon-cache` to make sure that the icon theme is set up correctly.  This results in a stale `${datarootdir}/icons/hicolor/icon-theme.cache` file being left over.  Since it was the addition of the Info file that broke things, I assumed that that was the problem.